# How to assign to struct fields from an array of values in order?

Tags: go, struct

I know you can create a struct with a literal, listing the fields in order:

```
type Foo struct {
    A string 
    B string
    C string 
}

foo := Foo{ "foo", "bar", "baz" }
```

Is there any way to do the same thing dynamically? I have an array of values (actually an array of arrays) and I want to assign them to an array of structs in field order, and there are rather more than three fields.  Is there a way to say "assign this struct's fields from this array of values in order"?  I really don't want to write a bunch of `structArray[i].field1 = dataArray[i][0]; structArray[i].field2 = dataArray[i][1]`, etc.

My thoughts so far have been to use `reflect`, which seems overkillish, or maybe to create an array of field names and build json strings and unmarshal them. Any better ideas?

Comment: In order to dynamically assign fields, you need to use `reflect`. Using `json` is just indirectly using `reflect` for the same thing. If this is primarily used around serialization, why not use a map?

Comment: In this case the struct is required by a module interface, not just one I've made up. Otherwise a map would work better, yes, since  I could pair up keys from my array of field names with values without having to go through `json`/`reflect`.

Comment: Using `reflect` is not overkillish if what you want is to dynamically assign fields in a language that's statically typed.

Answer (score 4):

With reflection you can write a function like this:

```
func populate(dst any, src any) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    if v.Type().Kind() != reflect.Pointer {
        panic("dst must be a pointer")
    }
    v = v.Elem()
    if v.Type().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("dst must be a pointer to struct")
    } 

    w := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    if w.Type().Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("src must be a slice")
    }
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        // in case you need to support source slices of arbitrary types
        value := w.Index(i)
        if value.Type().Kind() == reflect.Interface {
            value = value.Elem()
        }
        v.Field(i).Set(value)
    }
}
```

You must make sure that `dst` is addressable, hence pass a pointer to `Foo` into `populate`; and that the i-th element in the source slice is actually assignable to the corresponding i-th field in the struct.

The code above is in a quite simplified form. You can add additional checks to it, e.g. with `CanAddr` or `AssignableTo`, if you think callers may misbehave.

Call it like:

```
func main() {
    f := Foo{}
    populate(&f, []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"})
    fmt.Println(f) // {foo bar baz}
}
```

Here's a playground that also shows that you can pass a slice of `[]any` as the source slice, in case the struct fields aren't all the same type: https://go.dev/play/p/G8qjDCt79C7